# How to make a bash script that will carry out set of commands on a new server?

Tags: bash, shell

I open a Debian based server every other day and it would be nice to have a script that will execute the set of commands that I usually do manually automatically. This includes installing `zip`, downloading the latest Wordpress package with `wget`, installing `php5-curl` etc.

How do I set a bash script that will execute these commands from a specific path?:

```
apt-get install zip

wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip

rm -rf public_html

unzip latest.zip

mv wordpress public_html

a2enmod rewrite

apt-get install php5-curl

chown -R www-data public_html 

service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `#!/bin/bash` as first line. Add `cd your_specific_directory` and make it executable with `chmod +x name_of_your_script`.

Comment: and to simply add the text as it is? will it for example wait for wget to finish?

Comment: Yes. Add the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), a line with `cd` (e.g. `cd /tmp`) and append rest of your script.